# Why doesn't firebase admin messaging send notifications to all device token in multicast?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I know there are lot of questions around this question, and I promise I've checked quiet a number of them but non seems to give me an exact answer

I'm using firebase cloud function's admin messaging SDK to send push notifications to an array of device token I put together from my users collection.

The code:

```
  let deviceToken = [<device tokens>];
  let payload = {
    notification: {
      title: main_title,
      body: notf_body,
    },
    data: {
     <data object>
    },
  };
  await messaging
    .sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Successfully sent message to::", response.successCount);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
} else {
  console.log("ARTICLE PUBLISHED BUT NOT BROADCASTED");
  return;
}
```

seems to be working fine but the push notification is never sent to all the device token in the array...

Below is a log of the function triggered, where **49** device token are present in the array but only **32** notifications are successful

[image: function log]

What could be the reason for this, as some clients have been complaining they aren't getting notification

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for that, I've worked on a edit, hope this meet up with standard and gets the needed help

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some reasons why sending a message to a token might fail. The specific reason for each token that failed is specified in the `response.results` that you get back.

The most common reasons are that tokens get outdated/expired over time, meaning they won't work anymore. In a well working app, you'll register new tokens for the those same devices, but failure to clean up the old tokens from your database will result in more and more failures over time.

For a good example of how to deal with these errors and clean up outdated tokens, see this code from the example of [sending notifications in Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L87-L108):

```
// Listing all tokens as an array.
tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
// Send notifications to all tokens.
const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
// For each message check if there was an error.
const tokensToRemove = [];
response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
  const error = result.error;
  if (error) {
    functions.logger.error(
      'Failure sending notification to',
      tokens[index],
      error
    );
    // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
    if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
        error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
      tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
    }
  }
});
return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
```